# Management tools for configuration properties in the same style as tools like liquibase and flyway?

Tags: configuration-management

I'm wondering if there are any existing tools that allow for management on configuration properties (like Java properties files, or other similar formats) in the same style as database migration tools like liquibase and flyway.

I'd like a better way of managing my application's configuration properties which would allow me to track their evolution over time.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it enough if all config is externalized and version controlled? Tracking evolution then is just a matter of version history. Unlike db migration scripts, config doesn't execute to upgrade something to version x to verion y. The continuous delivery [book](http://martinfowler.com/delivery.html) says:

> Generally, we consider it bad practice to inject configuration
>   information at build or packaging time. This follows from the
>   principle that you should be able to deploy the same binaries to every
>   environment so you can ensure that the thing that you release is the
>   same thing that you tested.

And then there is this advice to store it all as [environment](http://www.12factor.net/config) variables.